# setting the given json response in Jcookie and retrieving it

Tags: jquery, json, cookies

I have a json string/ javascript list that I would like to save in jcookies

the json string/javascript list looks like

```
    [  { "depot":  {  "id": "D1",  "intersection": {  "first": "Markham",  "second": "Lawrence"  },  "address": {  "number": "25",  "street": "Cougar Court",  "city": "Scarborough",  "province": "ON",  "postal_code": "M1J3C5"  }  }, "vehicle": [  {  "id": "V1",  "depot_id": "D1",  "model": "Ford Focus",  "price": "45",  "km_per_litre": "15",  "cargo_cu_m": "120",  "category": "Compact car",  "image": "https://www.avis.com/car-rental/images/global/en/rentersguide/vehicle_guide/hyundaiaccent-ca-08.gif"  }       ] }
 ]
```

Please tell me how can I store this in the cookie and retrieve this from the cookie (into a javascript variable)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4225030/jquery-save-json-data-object-in-cookie
or 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483170/jquery-json-stringify-not-getting-the-entire-json-string-to-store-to-cookie
might help u

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you really do have the value already available as a string, you should be able to use the jquery cookie plugin https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie to save the value like so:

```
$.cookie('jsonList', jsonString);
```

and retrieve it like this:

```
jsonString = $.cookie('jsonList');
```

Comment: I tried that but when I try to access some value in it using dataArray[i].vehicle its says its  dataArray[i].vehicle is undefined

Comment: well you have to deserialize the json back into a js object before you can reference it like that - jsObj = $.parseJSON(jsonString); Then you could refer to jsObj[i].vehicle.

Comment: i tried that , I get 
JSON.parse: unexpected character
[Break On This Error] return window.JSON.parse( data );
jquery-latest.js (line 567)

Comment: So is your "string" really a string?  Can you alert it?  If so, are you sure it's valid JSON?  Run it through http://jsonlint.com/ to find out.